# mule: how to add value to payload array list

Tags: mule

I have a payload as list of maps and another flow variable as map.
I wanted to add flow variable to payload list. I tried using this expression `#[payload.addAll(flowVars['entitlement'])]`in expression component. But it sets the payload to boolean value true.

Answer (score 1):

Use expression component like

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[payload.addAll(flowVars['entitlement'])]]></expression-component>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Set Payload** transformer.
and add

## [payload.addAll(flowVars['entitlement']) as value.

Answer (score 0):

You set the payload as *the value returned by [addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))*. It's like doing `payload = payload.addAll(flowVars['entitlement'])` in Java `addAll()` returns a boolean, that's why your payload becomes `true`.

You can use instead:

```
#[payload.addAll(flowVars['entitlement']); payload)
```

This will perform your `addAll()` operation on your payload and *then* return this modified payload afterward. `;` allow your to perform [multiple expressions in MEL](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/mule-expression-language-reference#line-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave transform component and add the elements in various ways like using the ++ operator or use map operator to change the structure as per your requirements.